# block join query parser - need to fetch child document based on match either in child or in parent or in both

Tags: join, solr, parent-child

Hi I have following document structure:

```js
{
  "_childDocuments_": [{
    "id": 6186039,
    ....
    "title_s": "doctitle text to be matched childone",
    ....
  }, {
    "id": 6186038,
    ....
    "title_s": "doctitle text to be matched childtwo",
    ....
  }, {
    "id": 6186037,
    ....
    "title_s": "doctitle text to be matched childthree",
    ....
  }],
  "id": 6186040,
  ....
  "title_s": "parenttitle doctitle to be matched",
  ....
}
```

I want to fetch the child documents if:
1. title matched in child
2. title matched in parent
3. title matched in both child and parent

I have tried various combinations but fail to meet all three conditions in one query

can any one have idea about how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any way to distinguish between parent and child then it will be much easier to query. For example, to query when parent title is known, you can use {!child of=allParents}title_s:*parentTitle* where you can replace allParents by some criteria which identifies the parent document for example adding a type. For example if type is added then for all parent docs, type is parent and for childs it is child. then query will become {!child of=type:parent}title_s:*parentTitle*.

If you have child title then you can query with two filter queries as type:child and title_s:*childTitle*

For reference about block join query, refer to : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers

Comment: I have added type field but above suggestion will give me child document but my concern is fetching only child document based on matches found either in child or in parent or in both. I want to get this using single call to solr using multiple block join queries or whatever is the best. I also have multiple text fields to search like description field so can you suggest on how to add multiple child queries

Comment: In my knowledge, i don't think this will be possible as solr doesn't support multiple filter queries with OR operation (if it was ,then we can do what you asked in a single query by doing OR of two queries mentioned above). There is also a jira issue open for this : [SOLR-1223](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1223).